# Azure AD B2C - getting social media token, telephone number and changing email address?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying out Azure AD B2C at the moment to see if it will fit my app.

I will only be using Facebook and LinkedIn for sign-in/log-in. No email accounts etc.

Q1. When editing the profile, I can't change the email address. Email is not available as the attribute in Edit Profile policy. Once signed up, I went to Linkedin and directly changed the email address there. When signed in back to the app, old email address was still being returned in Claims array. Is there any way to change user's email on the microsoftonline website? Graph api seems like the only option, but that means that I need to handle it myself - verify if the email exists etc (which is kinda against the B2C idea in first place)?

Q2. I enabled multi-factor authentication for my sign-up policy. Is there any way to retrieve that tel no once verified? Again, it is not avilable in Claims for the Sign-up policy.

Q3. I would like to retrieve user's thumbnail (whether logged in via linkedin or facebook). Is there any way to get the social media token after the social media signin?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

These are great questions/feature requests. I would encourage you to vote for it in UserVoice (some links below - feel free to add a new entry if it's not exactly what you want)

Q1. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15529626-update-azure-ad-b2c-claims-when-signing-in-with-so

Q2. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18493399-gather-user-authentication-phone-and-authenticatio

Q3. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334347-return-social-idp-s-native-access-tokens-back-to-t

Comment: Thanks. Done. I also raised 2 more.